# ¿Cómo hacer que un SwipeRefreshLayout no se lancé cuando estoy utilizando un mapa de Google?

Tags: java, android-studio, layout

Estoy trabajando en Android Studio, tengo un SwipeRefreshLayout y dentro de este un WebvIew que carga un mapa de Google, lo que sucede es que cuando intento moverme por el mapa y deslizo desde arriba el WebView se actualiza haciendo imposible utilizar el mapa correctamente, ¿existe alguna forma de solucionar esto?..

El código del Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mainWV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" >

</WebView>
```

Comment: Porque no reemplazas el SwipeRefreshLayout por un icono en el toolbar?

Comment: si, creo que al final tendré que hacer eso hasta que encuentre una solución, lastima, porque el SwipeRefresh se mira y trabaja bien.